# WindowsPhone 8.1 - Application Bar position

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, application-bar

I'm forced to change look of ApplicationBar on application that runs on WindowsPhone 8.1. I need application bar to be on top not bottom. I tried to google it, but didn't come up with any simple solution. I'm not very experienced on this platform, so I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any way to do this with the standard application bar

But you can do your own control - put a simple Grid with several AppBarButton controls at the top of your page. If you want more advanced functionality like handling orientation changes, menu items, etc. .. you will have to program them yourself.